# Home page ("Feed"?) not working

Tags: bug, android-app

[image: Screenshot of home page]

And the screen when you swipe in from the right doesn't work. I don't even know what it is supposed to be.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: XT1068

  - OS Version: 6.0 (31)

Comment: It works fine for me. I notice you have a weak WiFi connection. The app is weird on slow connections, and won't load certain things in right away. Go onto mobile data (that looks strong) and close and reopen the app.

Comment: No doubt the most frequent bug, and 100% ignored by SE team. We have to live with the bugs, as I honestly don't think they will ever be fixed. (However I'm thankful we got app at all, and can still use it.)

Comment: @Zacharee1 judging from the amount of these same reports (at least 10 in last couple of months) many people got "slow connection".

Comment: Ok, so now it works. I feel mildly stupid. But now both the Feed and the notification tab are working. Edit: It works out with the mobile network as well. I don't know what was wrong for the last three days.